# 2019 Joomla Stack Exchange Pro Tempore Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

Starting on July 8, users can nominate themselves for [the announced Joomla Stack Exchange Pro Tempore Election](https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/q/357/12352).

Candidates should tell a bit about themselves and why they wish to become [a diamond moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75189/352329) and join the [JSE moderation team](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators).

To a large degree, what is expected of a moderator has been formed into carefully crafted documents over time -- some more philosophical than others -- here's just a small sample to inform and guide your thinking:

- [A Theory of Moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/) (2009)
- [Moderator Pro Tempore](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/27/moderator-pro-tempore/) (2010)
- [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75189/352329) (2011)
- [Experimenting with Pro Tempore elections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314459/352329) (2018)

---

We didn't do a [Question Collection](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380600/2943403) so we don't get a [Questionaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380885/2943403) so let's mock one up and call it practice for the next election.

Unless a miracle occurs and we are able to forge a JSE Questionare in one week from this page, let's compile a list of questions here for the nominees.  Here's the structure that I have in mind...

Though it seems somewhat counter-intuitive, **questions posed to the candidates should be posted on this page as "answers"**.

**Candidates should write their responses to questions into their self-nomination post** (preferably in an itemised fashion).

If you like a question and really want to see the candidates answer it, upvote it.  If you don't value a question or the answers that it would receive, downvote it.  Candidates may wish to respond to all questions or merely the ones that are highest voted.

Leave comments under respective "answers" on this page if you wish the author to clarify the question or if you want to explain your downvote.

Populating this page with questions for candidates is important for at least two reasons:

1. It gets everyone in the community thinking about community governance.  It's a pulse check.  Is the current moderation team doing a good job?  Is there anything lacking?  Can anything be improved?  What kind of a person would make a good addition? Where should we focus in the future?
2. It leads candidates about what things they can/should express in their candidacy pitch. Otherwise, we are more likely to see lackluster posts like:

   > *Hi I'm Jason, I use Joomla and I like JSE.  Vote for me!         **¯\_( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)_/¯***

p.s. These elections are meant to be fun and engaging, so pitch in and enjoy yourself.

Comment: ...to anyone new to meta, please vote freely.  There is no impact on rep points here.

Comment: My answers are here: https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/q/373/12352

Answer (score 3):

As per [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9953/235650) and https://medium.com/@jayhanlon/welcome-wagon-dd57cbdd54d9 etc, Stack Exchange websites are often accused of poor treatment of new users. How will you ensure that new users have a positive first experience of Joomla Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 2):

Please express the depth and breadth of your experience with:

1. [Joomla](https://www.joomla.org/about-joomla.html)
2. [Mambo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mambo_(software)) (if you go that far back) and
3. the [Stack Exchange Network](https://stackexchange.com/sites)

Comment: Not sure if any experience with Mambo counts - I don't think it should be on the list.

Answer (score 2):

Have you conducted any activities outside of JSE which encourage/promote JSE?

Answer (score 2):

Are there any occurrences on JSE which you will endeavour to prevent or encourage?  Please clarify the nature of these occurrences, why you are keeping an eye out for them, and how you intend to engage with the associated users.

Answer (score 2):

With your new moderator tool belt, what sorts of tasks are you looking forward to tackling?

Answer (score 2):

If a posted question is essentially a programming issue that is not exclusive to Joomla but was encountered during Joomla development, should it be migrated to another network or allowed to stay on JSE?  Please justify your response.

Answer (score 2):

Have you volunteered in any other areas of the Joomla community?

Answer (score 1):

As a moderator, if there are little or no new posts, comments, or flags to review since your last check in, what tasks will you undertake to best benefit JSE?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any experience moderating other Stack Exchange websites or other similar forums?

Answer (score 0):

On Stack Overflow, it has been said that [elected moderators should be dedicating at least 30 minutes per day to their duties](https://stackoverflow.com/election/11). The Joomla Stack Exchange community doesn't receive the same volume of daily actions from its members, but then it doesn't have as many moderators either.  If you do not intend to invest 30 minutes or more per day, how much time are you willing to commit and why do you feel that that amount is sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

Elected moderators enjoy a lifetime term.  It is not likely that someone will tap a moderator on the shoulder and ask them to step down (especially if there has been no behavioral violation) because that might be too rude/confrontational.  If elected as a moderator, how will you decide when it is time to step and make way for a new moderator?

Comment: I wouldn't want to ask a candidate's exit strategy before they've even been elected :)

Comment: No end game in mind?

Comment: I see the angle you're coming from here. Just not something I'd ask

Answer (score 0):

What are your aspirations for this community?  Do you have any measurable goals that you would like this community to achieve?

Answer (score -4):

JSE has a high volume of [EASL](https://www.acronymfinder.com/English-As-a-Second-Language-(EASL).html) contributors.  How important is it that posts are edited to use proper spelling, grammar, and punctuation?  Are you capable of interpreting and improving broken English without damaging the intent of the author's post?

Comment: Good questions need good grammar, spelling and overall good english language usage - but it's not a moderator's responsibility to edit and correct the language of such posts.

Comment: Feel free to downvote.  It is not offensive in this process.  I'll want to know which topics to detail in my nomination.  And, by all means, add your own questions to candidates; I don't want to monopolise this page.

Comment: I sometimes edit questions I see if I feel they might be a problem for poeple to understand (assuming I actually understand if myself), however I do feel it's not up to moderators to perform this task, but instead the user themselves.

Comment: It is okay to take this stance.  I only mean to stir up the thoughts of the community with some of these questions is about "role modeling".  Moderator actions are likely to be emulated, so having moderators with an extensive suite of abilities is impactful.